# How can I insert and get PK Id using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net

currently I'm Inserting like:

```
MyNamedEntities db = new MyNamedEntities();

MyTableEntity field = new MyTableEntity();
field.Name = "me";

db.MyTableEntity.AddObject(field);
db.SaveChanges()
```

But now I want to insert child elements and I need that `field.Id` part

```
MyOtherTableEntity field = new MyOtherTableEntity();
field.TableId = new MyTableEntity.First(x => x.Id.Equals( ... ));
```

How can I get the `field.Id` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your table has defined the `Id` as an `INT IDENTITY` column, then you don't really have to do anything at all! :-)

In that case, just insert your entity and after the call to `.SaveChanges()`, your object should contain the new `Id` value:

```
MyTableEntity field = new MyTableEntity();
field.Name = "me";

db.MyTableEntity.AddObject(field);
db.SaveChanges();

int newID = field.Id;
```

Comment: wow, never saw about this... it's quite easy then :) my PK are always Decimal (numeric) or Int (int). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add them to the parent by the association before or after the save changes
Something like this.

address a = new address();
a.city = "Detroit";
field.address.add(a);

db.SaveChanges();

Comment: humm ... that's new! I will try it, that's much better and everything will hook up automatically with PK and FK.